# radgridview access column in the same level

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview

Hi I want to apply a style names "DataColumnStyle" on a column "colA" in my radgridview if an other column "colB" is invisble but I didn't find how to acces to the visibility of "colB".

```
<Style x:Key="DataColumnStyle"
           TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding BienEtService.PolitiquePrixBes.PrixVenteTTC,
                                Mode=OneWay,
                                StringFormat='{}{0:0.00 €}'}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                                 Path=IsVisible}"
                               Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Orange" />
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to bind to the column if you know its index within the `Columns` collection of the parent `RadGridView`:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadGridView}, Path=Columns[0].IsVisible}" Value="True" />
```

You can't bind to it by name though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but sorry, the order of columns can change. I have the UniqueName of the column if this can be helpfull

Comment: No. There is no other pure XAML solution that I can think of. You could try to bind the IsVisible property of the column and the condition to the same source property.

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it as you said . I create an other property to get the visibility of the column and I bind it to style.
thanks